# SSRS 2008 parameter to show more values if user wants

Tags: reporting-services

I want my SSRS parameter to show the last 10 values of my predefined dataset for the parameter, but an 11th value would be added as 'More...' this would make the parameter to Show ALL the available values for that parameter if the user Clicks on the "More..." Value

Trying to replicate the idea or find a picture on the web...will post with an update. But hopefully you guys understand what I am trying to do.

I have researched but I have had no actual results, many talk about cascading parameters I know how to do that but I do see it as a neat solution, user friendly for my High tier executive bosses that will be using these Reports.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a functionality in SSRS, but you can resolve it using this workaround:

1.Modify the dataset for your parameter, adding new parameter for this query, e.g.:

```
    IF @PARAM = 'False'

    SELECT TOP 10
    [custid]
    FROM [TSQL2012].[Sales].[Customers]

    ELSE 

    SELECT 
    [custid]
    FROM [TSQL2012].[Sales].[Customers]
```

If this `@PARAM`  parameter is 'false' select only 10 values for your parameter list, else select all values for the parameter list.

2.Add new parameter to your report, named @PARAM (data type= boolean, default value = 'false'). This parameter has to be created before your target parameter.

Your parameters in report should work as follows:
[image: Show only 10 values for the parameter]

[image: Show all values for the parameter]

Comment: yeah i ended up doing something like that. I believe its called cascading parameters. And used a Dynamic SQL query to have that same functionality you proposed. 

I thought that functionality is not available because it would require the SSRS to render the List of values in real time. But I know SSRS renders and loads data when a click is done to the parameter list.